# How to replace text in a bash script between specific characters with content from another file?

Tags: html, bash

My question is similar to this [other posted question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154352/replace-data-at-specific-positions-in-txt-file-using-data-from-another-file?rq=1):
but I only need to be able to replace the code between and including two html comments (...) with code from another file altogether.

For example, in aSample.htm, I want to replace the code between the "test1" comments:

```
<!-- test1 Begin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
      "http://www.aServer.com/template/style.css">
<!-- test1 End -->
```

with code from another file (example template.txt) :

```
<!-- Changes Begin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
    "/srv/anotherServer.com/htdocs/api/test/cfHtmlHeadTest.css">
<!-- Changes End -->
```

My script so far will wget all html files from a given ip address ($ip) and create a new directory for them.  Here's what I tried using for the replacement based on another site I searched on:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_FILE=$(cat./template.txt)
TARGETFILE='app/HtmlPages/"$ip-$currentTime"/"$ip"/index.php/art/*.htm'
STARTTAG="test1 Begin"
ENDTAG="test1 End" 

# stuff

# Replaces all htm files' content between $START-/ENDTAG by inserting line from template.txt
echo "css replacement test..."
sed -e "s&\(<\!\-\-\$STARTTAG\-\->\).*\(<\!\-\-\$ENDTAG\-\->\)&\1$TEST_FILE\2&"
```

Before adding this change, the code ran as expected.  When I made the change, however, the system freezes or takes a long time to process, which I wouldn't expect for such a small change.  I've tried other sed commands (e.g. variants of [this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77549/replacing-text-between-two-html-comments)), but I got an "unknown option to 's'"...

Did I leave something out or does anyone know what the system is doing?

Comment: `sed` is line-based. It can't (by default) operate on patterns that span lines.

Comment: This will be a nightmare to do in sed, I would suggest using awk or perl instead

Comment: Oh! Okay, thank you.  I  haven't used 'awk' a lot, but here is what I am trying (and failing with):


`awk '{sub(/<!-- $STARTTAG -->.*<!-- $ENDTAG -->/, "<!-- Changes Begin -->" env[$TEST_FILE] "<!-- Changes End -->"); print}'`

The system is still being tied up when I ran this, but is this the right track, at least??

Comment: * With `export $TEST_FILE` on the line before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed's `r` command to read the contents of a file at the appropriate time.

```
$ cat aSample.htm 
foo
<!-- test1 Begin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
      "http://www.aServer.com/template/style.css">
<!-- test1 End -->
bar

$ cat template.txt
<!-- Changes Begin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
    "/srv/anotherServer.com/htdocs/api/test/cfHtmlHeadTest.css">
<!-- Changes End -->

$ sed '
  /<!-- test1 End -->/ r template.txt
  /<!-- test1 Begin -->/,/<!-- test1 End -->/ d
' aSample.htm
```

```
foo
<!-- Changes Begin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
    "/srv/anotherServer.com/htdocs/api/test/cfHtmlHeadTest.css">
<!-- Changes End -->
bar
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  (I'll be testing some more and researching this command so I better understand;  your solution is much cleaner than what I have been trying.)

Comment: The [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is worth bookmarking.

Comment: Hey, it worked beautifully! I couldn't use my variables (yet, since they're messed up a little on my end), but when I ran it as you specified, I saw the changes.  Thanks again!